# Fastest way to draw large, coloured grids in WPF without using third party libraries?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I need to represent a large amount of real time data in a coloured grid (about ~100 by ~150, and may grow in the future). What's the best practice in achieving this in WPF, without resorting to third party libraries or controls? The data is updated several times per second, so the display needs to be reasonably responsive.

I've previously used WinForm for this, by overriding OnPaint in a panel. But it is [apparently bad practice](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2009/09/08/onrender-is-not-as-cheap-as-onpaint/) to do this in (what I think is) the WPF equivalent, OnRender in a Canvas. So I'm wondering what the best practice is, for my particular use case.

Comment: How quickly does the view need to update?

Comment: @AdamBrown Let's say every 50 ms.

Comment: First thing to consider is the fact that MVVM allows optimizing the screen updates. Probably not all of the 15K cells are going to change every 50 ms? If you devise a view model that keeps track of current values in grid cells, you may be able to use pretty standard approach to MVVM UI design. The values in view model will announce their changes via property change notifications and view binds the values to its properties. 

While the whole setup may look ridiculously complex, the runtime changes actually propagate very effiently. Repainting everything in one pass may turn out less effient.

Comment: @CongenitalOptimist Most of the cells actually would change by small amounts every update, because of random noise in the readings, though  I suppose I could ignore changes below a certain threshold. What I'm confused about though is how the view should be updated in WPF. I shouldn't be loading 15,000 separate controls onto a canvas, right?

Comment: You could actually. The data that controls hold is mainly kept in the dependency properties which are compacted in memory. If we look at the amount of properties that each UIElement or Control class can have in its interface, we see huge structures. In practice the default values are not duplicated in memory, values are kept in dictionaries etc. I'm not saying that WPF is a lightweight thing. However, I'm coming from Win32 and C++, while transfering to WPF I have had similar doubts. Today I think large number of controls is OK. The efficiency pitfall is in (bad) orchestrating of update events.

Comment: @CongenitalOptimist Huh. That is really super counter intuitive, but interesting. I will give that a try, thanks .

Answer (score 1):

For drawing on Canvas I have created custom controls derived from FrameworkElement. If there are smaller things inside the control (like cells in your case) one could have multiple Visual objects inside that FrameworkElement.

Here's an (untested) example of class that implements something like this. It does not override OnRender but just populates the Visuals inside. It is up to you how to define and when to update the inner Visuals (meaning the implementation of Populate function).

```
public class CanvasDrawingObject : FrameworkElement
{
    VisualCollection m_children;
    DrawingVisual m_drawingVisual;

    public CanvasDrawingObject( )
        : base( )
    {
        m_children = new VisualCollection(this);
        m_drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        m_children.Add(m_drawingVisual);
    }

    public void PopulateMyContent( )
    {
        // place it somewhere
        Canvas.SetLeft(this, 7);
        Canvas.SetTop(this, 42);

        // draw
        DrawingContext context = this.DrawingVisual.RenderOpen();
        if (context != null)
        {
            // do your drawing
            //context.DrawLine(... );
            context.Close();
        }
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return m_children.Count; }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= m_children.Count)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        return m_children[index];
    }
}
```

That said, the application where I used similar construct has no true real-time requirements, but it is used for drawing lots of vector graphics and text.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Performance issues aside, here is what I think is a fairly elegant MVVM-based solution for the binding, although you might find that its simplicity helps keep the performance sweet.

I'm assuming you have a class representing each data point, e.g.:

```
public class DataPoint : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _value;

    public int X {get;set;}

    public int Y {get;set;}

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (_value!= value)
            {
               _value= value;
               OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation ommitted for brevity
}
```

The X and Y properties are the point's position in your grid, so would be assigned [0,0], [0, 1] ... [99, 149].

Next, expose a collection of these objects via your VM:

```
public List<DataPoint> DataPoints {get; private set;}
```

(You may need to use an `ObservableCollection instead, depending on how/where you instantiate and populate the collection).

In the XAML, bind an `ItemsControl` to this collection, and use a `Canvas` as its ItemsPanelTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataPoints}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DataPointStyle}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="150" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

(I've kept this example simple by setting the canvas size to 100x150, so each "data point" will be 1x1 pixel).

And here is the item container style:

```
<Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataPoint}">
                <Border Width="1" Height="1" 
                        Background="{Binding Value, Converter={...}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This binds the list item's `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties to the model's X and Y properties. The item template is just a 1x1 border whose background is bound to the model's Value property (you'll need a value converter to convert the integer value to a 'Color' based on your requirements).

Using 1x1 borders means you'll run into issues unless you `SnapToDevicePixels`. You can of course make the border larger than 1x1 pixel - you'll need a value converter on the 'Canvas.Left' and 'Canvas.Top' bindings that multiplies the bound value by the size of the "square" that you need.

(This code is mostly dumped from memory so no guarantees it will work out of the box, but should get you on your way!)

I'd be interested to know how it handles performance. Our application is a "soft real-time" system that updates hundreds of controls every 100ms, but still a long way off the numbers you are dealing with!

Comment: This looks like a very clean solution. Thank you, I will try see how well it works; but would it be possible to print the value out as well doing it this way? (It would be impossible to see the text in the full view of course, but it would be helpful to display it when zoomed in on a spot)

Comment: To zoom in you can set the LayoutTransform on Canvas. To print, the simplest method is using System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog method PrintVisual. 
To allow user a quick look into a small item in UI you can use ToolTip which in case of WPF can contain anything, not just line of text.

Comment: @Semaphore you could include a TextBlock (bound to the Value property) inside the Border. The grid would need to be fairly big to read the text, but you could implement some kind of zooming, although this isn't something I've had to do. One idea may be to wrap the ItemsControl in a ViewBox, and place this in a fixed width/height ScrollViewer. Resize the ViewBox based on (say) mouse wheel events then use the scrollbars to pan around, or better still implement panning using mouse down/drag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use a Canvas to output the necessary display. Given your very high refresh rate, it might also be necessary to do some frame synchronisation using the CompositionTarget.Rendering event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you elaborate a bit please? Do you m ean putting my drawing functions inside this CompositionTarget.Rendering event?

Comment: I would probably just ignore that for now. Just use a canvas to draw and see if it's OK. You only need to worry about CT.Rendering if you get tearing.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I meant, where can I be manually drawing on a canvas? I tried it in OnRender before finding the article I linked in the question, and the program ground to a halt.